# When changing list item layout RecyclerView scrolls to top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-adapter

In my `RecyclerView` OnLongClicking an item I want to change that item's layout by setting some `TextViews` to `View.GONE` and others to `View.VISIBLE`. Everything works except that when I long press the item and the layout changes my `RecyclerView` scrolls to top and I can no longer see the LongPressed view if it was at the bottom.

This is `ListAdapter` that I wrote:

```
class AssetsListAdapter(
    private val onAssetClickListener: OnAssetClickListener,
    private val onAssetLongClickListener: OnAssetLongClickListener
) :
    ListAdapter<Asset, AssetsListAdapter.ViewHolder>(
        AssetDiffCallback()
    ) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(
            inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.list_item,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position), onAssetClickListener, onAssetLongClickListener)
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bind(
            asset: Asset,
            onAssetClickListener: OnAssetClickListener,
            onAssetLongClickListener: OnAssetLongClickListener
        ) {
            itemView.item_name.text = asset.name

            // Set icons relatively to category
            when (asset.category) {
                "Cash" -> itemView.item_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cash)
                "Bank Account" -> itemView.item_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bank)
                "Investment" -> itemView.item_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_invest)
                "Salary" -> itemView.item_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_job)
            }

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onAssetClickListener.onAssetClick(asset)
            }

            // On long click listeners pulls up quick action options
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
                view.item_end_text.visibility = View.GONE
                view.quick_actions_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                onAssetLongClickListener.onAssetLongClick(asset, itemView)
                true
            }
        }

    }

    class AssetDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Asset>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Asset, newItem: Asset): Boolean {
            return oldItem.assetId == newItem.assetId
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Asset, newItem: Asset): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    interface OnAssetClickListener {
        fun onAssetClick(asset: Asset)
    }

    interface OnAssetLongClickListener {
        fun onAssetLongClick(asset: Asset, view: View)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out that if you set `View.GONE` the whole item is redrawn and it resets the `RecyclerView`? Because setting it to `View.INVISIBLE` solves the issue.

```
itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
            view.item_end_text.visibility = View.GONE
            view.quick_actions_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            onAssetLongClickListener.onAssetLongClick(asset, itemView)
            true
        }
```

to

```
itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
                view.item_end_text.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                view.quick_actions_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                onAssetLongClickListener.onAssetLongClick(asset, itemView)
                true
            }
```